# how to mark a directory as resource bundle directory in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying **IntelliJ** to see how it compares with **Eclipse** in Java development. I have imported code formatter from Eclipse and figured out most of the new things in Intellij. But more things need to be learned:

Question 1:

I have a **resources** folder and then an **i18n** folder under it. All my resource bundle files are inside the **i18n** folder. How can I tell Intellij to treat these files as the resource bundle file and associate them with a resource bundle editor?

Question 2:

Why Intellij gives me the * for the java.awt and javax.swing packages?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
```

How to make them down to class name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question 1, you can mark the folder as a Resource file in Project Structure
[image]

Check [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html) for more information.

For question 2, this is about `Disable wildcard imports﻿`

1. In the Settings/Preferences dialog ⌘,, select Code Style | Java |
   Imports.
2. Make sure that the Use single class import option is enabled.
3. In the Class count to use import with ‘*’ and Names count to use
   static import with ‘*’ fields, specify values that definitely exceed
   the number of classes in a package and the number of names in a
   class (for example, 999).

check [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-optimizing-imports.html) for more information

Hope it helps

Comment: It seems that the Resource folder is different from the Resouce Bundle folder: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/resource-bundle.html. Resource Bundle is for internationalization.

Comment: @peterboston, yes there is a difference, I missed that. Still you need to put the *_en files under the classpath, and import it into your project properties. You found the right documentation

Comment: Then how can I make Intellij know my i18n folder is a Resource Bundle folder?

Comment: The documentation is not enough? I think it makes very clear how to set up the resource bundle folder. `On the File menu, point to New and click Resource Bundle, or press ⌘N and click Resource Bundle.`

Comment: no, that doc tells people how to add a new resource bundle. I am not adding new resource bundle. I am asking Intellij recognize the existing resource bundles. I just found Intellij do recognize my existing resource bundle files but the associated editor is NOT good enough. For example, I have Chinese and English resource bundles. For Chinese, the editor only shows me the unicode. What I want, or what Eclipse has, is that, for Chinese, the editor will show me unicode and Chinese character. I can just input Chinese Character and the editor will translate it to unicode for me. Any plugin for this

Comment: @peterboston, I never realized this, but there is a Jira ticket related to this issue. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115049,  looks like some people have the trouble.

Comment: "select the Transparent native-to-ascii conversion checkbox on the File Encoding page of the Settings/Preferences dialog." is what I was missed. It can display Chinese characters now. I have a new issue, I don't know how to save the addition on the resource bundle file set.

Comment: additional? new language file or new keys in the file? You better create another question with some snapshots, so more people could help you.

Comment: add a new property item (key, value) in an existing file set. yes, a new question is created: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62033728/intellij-how-to-add-and-save-a-property-in-a-resource-bundle-file