# Intellij how to add and save a property in a resource bundle file?

Tags: intellij-idea

By following the steps on this [doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/resource-bundle.html), I was able to add a new property in an existing resource bundle file set in English and Chinese. But I don't know how to save this addition. Initially, it seems good. I click the save button several times and then navigate away from the newly added entry. When I came back, the new key is there but the values are gone. Looking at the files on the disk, only one file has the key, no other changes there. I am using the latest Intellij on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-237258) in 2020.1 and 2020.1.1 releases.

The [fix is available](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2020.1+latest+builds) since IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.2 RC  (build 201.7846.53), released on May 26, 2020.